# I have a question on tensorflow/tfjs LSTM inputShape and also LSTM basic understaning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, model, lstm, tensorflow.js

my training data set is for one user

```
let training = [
    [[2019.1], [10]],
    [[2019.2], [2]],
    [[2019.4], [11]],
    [[2019.5], [31]]
]
```

for this simple input I want to get next month prediction. To understand LSTM time series first. using below code for generating training model

```
let train_x = training.map(i => {return i[0]})
let train_y = training.map(j=> {return j[1]})

const model = tf.sequential();
**model.add(tf.layers.lstm({units: 128, returnSequences: false,  inputShape:[train_x.length]}));**
model.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: training.length, activation: 'softmax'}));

model.compile({loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: tf.train.rmsprop(0.002)});

**const xs = tf.tensor3d([train_x]);**
const ys = tf.tensor2d(train_y, [training.length, train_y[0].length]);
```

Error:

```
Error: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_LSTM1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

Problem is what input shape should be given and what should be tf.tensor3d input. For my understanding i am trying this simple example. Trying it without keras

Comment: As i have only this much data for a single user. I want to predict next month number example --> [[2019.6], [22]]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is straightforward:

```
Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_LSTM1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2
```

An lstm layer expects a 3d input. It means that the inputShape should be `[a, b]` where both `a` and `b` are numbers (`a` can be `null` as well). There is a single sequence of 2 elements. `a` is therefore `1` (single sequence: number of sequence we want the layer to see before making a prediction; looking at the data here it seems to be 1, but can be changed to a different value) and `b` is `2` (2 elements per sequence).

training would be:

```
training = [
    [[2019.1, 10]],
    [[2019.2, 2]],
    [[2019.4], [11]],
    [[2019.5], [31]]
]
xs = tf.tensor(training).reshape([-1, 1, 2])
```

And the lstm layer becomes the following:

```
model.add(tf.layers.lstm({units: 128, returnSequences: false,  inputShape:[1, 2]}));
```

And voilà, the whole model looks as below:

```
const model = tf.sequential();
model.add(tf.layers.lstm({units: 128, returnSequences: false,  inputShape:[1, 2]}));
model.add(tf.layers.dropout(0.2))
model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 20, activation: 'softmax'}));
model.summary()
model.compile({loss: 'categoricalCrossentropy', optimizer: tf.train.rmsprop(0.002)});
model.summary()
const training = [
        [[2019.1, 10]],
        [[2019.2, 2]],
        [[2019.4], [11]],
        [[2019.5], [31]]
    ]
const xs = tf.tensor(training).reshape([-1, 1, 2])
await model.fit(xs, tf.ones([4, 20]))
model.predict(tf.ones([1, 1, 2])).print()
```

Comment: got an output like this

[ 
0.02468624711036682,
  0.02503986470401287,
  0.026008365675807,
  0.024018235504627228,
  0.024773791432380676,
  0.025004612281918526,
  0.02489587850868702,
  0.025202354416251183,
  0.025096451863646507,
  0.024056443944573402,
  0.026048900559544563,
  0.026084518060088158
]

Comment: The length of your array is related to the `units` of the last layer. This question is already accepted. If you still have other issues, please consider opening a new thread

Comment: I Added this output for other people who will check this in future. so that they can be sure about output. Thanks